# Service on Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

On Android Oreo, If my app starts a service while in foreground and then I close my app, will the service be killed later on? or will it stay alive?

From this video post it seems like the service will be killed if the app is in background, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc&t=198s

However, while testing, the service is quite alive. Will appreciate any productive feedback.

Comment: Turns out I was not tarting api 26 in my app. Once I started targeting api 26, it shut down services when app was in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service gets killed eventually

> When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several
>   minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At
>   the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this
>   time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the
>   app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

Comment: Note that in my testing, "several minutes" is ~1 minute.

Comment: It would be nice if they actually gave us a narrower time window when we can expect things to stop

Answer (score 2):

The service´s call and all of your current aplication´s process will be killed if you close or destroy your application, cause all of these process are linked to your app´s lifecycle, if the lifecycle is closed, killed or crashed, all of the processes go to the same end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers! Appreciate your responses. It Was my bad as I switched the work branch that wasn't targeting API 26.
  I think, it's worth mentioning that the above restriction is only applicable if the app is targeting api 26 (Android O).
  I have started moving to Job scheduler, and that seems to be working on Android O.

Comment: "it's worth mentioning that the above restriction is only applicable if the app is targeting api 26 (Android O)" -- the user can also manually enable this restriction on Android 8.0+ for apps that consume a lot of battery, apparently.

Comment: @CommonsWare true, but the likelihood of majority of users doing it is very less

Comment: Agreed -- I just wanted to make sure that people reading your answer knew about it.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, and thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It really helps